# Fastest Magento 2 Environment

Tags: magento2, performance, development

I've recently installed Magento 2 on Vagrant with Scotch-box, Ubuntu. It takes about 30 to 60 seconds to load a page (front- and back-end). This is too much to work with as a developer.

As a solution I tried installing it local on XAMPP environment, it still takes 3 to 6 seconds to load a page which is too much to work with.

P.S I have XAMPP on Windows, 256SSD and i7.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try http://www.magestead.com/ ? it may work but best thing is setup your environment as @MauroNigrele describe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a custom-made vagrant with:

- box: ubuntu/trusty64
- Mysql 5.6
- PHP 5.6.17 - by ppa
- Nginx 1.8.0
- opCache (disabled)
- Redis for both Cache And Page Cache
- Memcacehd for sessions

Vagrant Config:

- CPU Cores: 1
- RAM: 2Gb
- Share by NFS

All code files placed in the host side on a MacBook Pro I7 - and is Working Flawless

I strongly recommend to avoid using local environments (like XAMP) *even more* if you are running windows.

Comment: And whats the load time with cache disabled?

Comment: I'm using something similar, Ubuntu, Mysql 5.6, Php 5.6, cache disabled, 2 CPU cores and 4GB RAM.

Comment: while developing without *opcache* and *varnish* and with: *Page* , *Blocks*, *Layout* and *Translation* Caches disabled: ~1.5 home,  ~2.3  Category Page (simple products) with configurables should be more.

Comment: Depending on "what are you doing" (backend/front/services) pick which caches you can to disable and try to keep always enabled config, eav, reflection, and ddl. In M1 I used to disable all, but now is impossible.

Comment: Thank you very much! Last question, how about Windows + Docker  + livereload (chrome extension) + gulp + magento 2 ?? via www.alankent.me

Comment: I read that blog post a few days ago, I love docker but for windows/mac environments you still needing a virtual machine to run docker (at least for now) so I don't see the any advantage with that approach. Anyway I prefer to use Docker Compose to orchestrate the containers. I didn't try gulp yet I'm using Grunt that actually sucks! but is what we have for now All Gulp tools I found doesn't support the magento's theme insane fallbacks